# Given two Java threads, stop one thread when one of them finishes

Tags: java, concurrency, runnable

I'm looking for a clean design/solution for this problem: I have two threads, that may run as long as the user wants to, but eventually stop when the user issues the stop command. However if one of the threads ends abruptly (eg. because of a runtime exception) I want to stop the other thread.

Now both threads execute a `Runnable` (so when I say 'stop a thread' what I mean is that I call a stop() method on the `Runnable` instance), what I'm thinking is to avoid using threads (Thread class) and use the `CompletionService` interface and then submit both Runnables to an instance of this service.

With this I would use the CompletionService's method `take()`, when this method returns I would stop both Runnables since I know that at least one of them already finished. Now, this works, but if possible I would like to know of a simpler/better solution for my case.

Also, what is a good solution when we have `n` threads and as soon as one of them finishes to stop execution of all the others ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no `stop()` method for the Runnable interface.

Comment: The implementation that I pass contains this method. The code has access to it so it can call stop().

Answer (score 7):

There is no `Runnable.stop()` method, so that is an obvious non-starter.

Don't use `Thread.stop()`!  It is fundamentally unsafe in the *vast majority* of cases.

Here are a couple of approaches that should work, if implemented correctly.

1. You could have both threads regularly check some common flag variable (e.g. call it `stopNow`), and arrange that both threads set it when they finish.  (The flag variable needs to be volatile ... or properly synchronized.)
2. You could have both threads regularly call the `Thread.isInterrupted()` method to see if it has been interrupted.  Then each thread needs to call `Thread.interrupt()` on the other one when it finishes.

---

> I know Runnable doesn't have that method, but my implementation of Runnable that I pass to the threads does have it, and when calling it the runner will finish the run() method (something like Corsika's code, below this answer).

From what I can tell, Corsika's code *assumes* that there is a `stop()` method that will do the right thing when called.  The real question is how have you do implemented it?  Or how do you intend to implement it?

- If you already have an implementation that works, then you've got a solution to the problem.
- Otherwise, my answer gives two possible approaches to implementing the "stop now" functionality.

> I appreciate your suggestions, but I have a doubt, how does 'regularly check/call' translate into code ?

It entirely depends on the task that the `Runnable.run()` method performs.  It typically entails adding a check / call to certain loops so that the test happens reasonably often ... but not too often.  You also want to check only when it would be safe to stop the computation, and that is another thing you must work out for yourself.

Comment: I know Runnable doesn't have that method, but my implementation of Runnable that I pass to the threads does have it, and when calling it the runner will finish the run() method (something like Corsika's code, below this answer). I appreciate your suggestions, but I have a doubt, how does 'regularly check/call' translate into code ?

Comment: I wanted to try what you suggested in point 2 above, but I have no clue how to make it work. I have posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22181552/interrupt-one-thread-inside-another-threads-run-method-in-java. please give your answer if you can. Thanks a lot

Comment: Option 2, with interruption, has the benefit of using a standard interface that can be invoked by things like an `ExecutorService`.

Comment: @erickson - yes, that is another advantage of using Java interrupts rather than an ad-hoc mechanism.

Answer (score 4):

The following should help to give you some ideas of how you might apply it to your problem. Hope it helps...

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class x {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            ThreadManager<Thread> t = new ThreadManager<Thread>();
            Thread a = new MyThread(t);
            Thread b = new MyThread(t);     
            Thread c = new MyThread(t);
            t.add(a);
            t.add(b);
            t.add(c);
            a.start();
            b.start();
            c.start();      
        }
    }

    class ThreadManager<T> extends ArrayList<T> {

        public void stopThreads() {
            for (T t : this) {
                Thread thread = (Thread) t;
                if (thread.isAlive()) {
                    try { thread.interrupt(); } 
                    catch (Exception e) {/*ignore on purpose*/}
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class MyThread extends Thread {

        static boolean signalled = false;

        private ThreadManager m;

        public MyThread(ThreadManager tm) {
            m = tm;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {           
                // periodically check ...
                if (this.interrupted()) throw new InterruptedException();
                // do stuff
            } catch (Exception e) {
                synchronized(getClass()) {
                    if (!signalled) {
                        signalled = true;
                        m.stopThreads();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Whether you use a stop flag or an interrupt, you will need to periodically check to see whether a thread has been signalled to stop.

Answer (score 1):

You could give them access to eachother, or a callback to something that had access to both so it could interrupt the other. Consider:

```
MyRunner aRunner = new MyRunner(this);
MyRunner bRunner = new MyRunner(this);
Thread a = new Thread(aRunner);
Thread b = new Thread(brunner);


// catch appropriate exceptions, error handling... probably should verify
// 'winner' actually is a or b
public void stopOtherThread(MyRunner winner) {
    if(winner == aRunner ) bRunner .stop(); // assumes you have stop on class MyRunner
    else aRunner.stop();
}

// later
a.start();
b.start();


// in your run method
public void run() {
    // la de da de da
    // awesome code
    while(true) fork();
    // other code here
    myRunnerMaster.stopOtherThread(this);
}
```

Comment: Do be aware that the [Thread.stop instance method is deprecated](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) for good reason.

Comment: @hd1 You're entirely correct. What you're seeing is a typo. That should be `aRunner.stop()` and `bRunner.stop()`, which I will correct momentarily.