# Unable to Cleanly Stop my Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have created a class which extends Thread.

This class has several methods defined, some of which use Process and IO streams to download files (sometimes taking several minutes).

I also have a JButton which I use to stop the thread, it has an ActionListener which currently performs a ClassName.this.stop(); and this works perfectly.

Within the 'public void run()' method, I execute some of these methods and start the thread.

My question is, how can I replace my deprecated Thread.stop() method with an interrupt(), and use it to cleanly stop the thread?

I have looked at some solutions, which recommend using a boolean flag to check whether the thread has been interrupted, but seeing that the run() method simply executes a series of methods, the loop does not evaluate until all the methods have finished executing, and even then, I get a 'InterrupedException' and then the loop starts again.

Another issue is that if a download is in progress, it could take minutes for the download to complete and for the next check to see if the Thread has been interrupted. I'd like everything to stop and for the object to 'delete itself and everything in it', which is what Thread.stop() is currently doing correctly.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Try something along these lines ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656244/given-two-java-threads-stop-one-thread-when-one-of-them-finishes/13659892#13659892

Comment: This article explains it in detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904072/java-difference-in-usage-between-thread-interrupted-and-thread-isinterrupted/62438836#62438836

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use extra boolean sentinel flags, rely fully on the interruption mechanism. In long-runnig tasks which don't spend time in interruptible blocking methods; you must handcode occasional checks of `Thread.interrupted()` and break out of the task if `true`. If your loop goes on after `InterruptedException`, then fix this behavior. This aspect is completely in your hands. Don't ignore the exception; react by curtailing the work and ending the method.

Comment: For me it doesn't make sense to add several IF checks to many different methods to check whether the thread has terminated. In some cases, the check won't get executed until a download has completed.

Comment: That's how interruptible code is written. If you are doing a download, then a lot of time is spent in blocking I/O code. Use interruptible I/O.

Comment: It seems like a lot of repetition, and when using loops which get executed several times per second this could slow it down. I don't need to very cleanly stop every aspect of the thread, I'd like everything to stop what it's doing and make itself available for GC. I'll read into interruptible I/O, thanks.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Why `interrupted` and not `isInterrupted`?

Comment: @assylias You tell me, I'm not sure myself which to recommend. Given that the `interrupted` flag is reset when a JDK method throws `InterruptedException`, this would be more in line with that behavior.

Comment: This article should guide you on how to deal with interrupted() and answer your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904072/java-difference-in-usage-between-thread-interrupted-and-thread-isinterrupted/62438836#62438836